# Sorting on nullable fields in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to sort on multiple fields in Grails 3, one of which may or may not be null. I have this Book domain:

```
class Book {

    String title
    String sortTitle

    static constraints = {
        title blank: false
        sortTitle nullable: true
    }
}
```

Books with titles like "The Peripheral" have a `sortTitle` of "Peripheral, The", otherwise `sortTitle` will be null. I want books sorted by `sortTitle` if one exists, otherwise by `title`.

I found other similar SO questions, but none with a nullable field. Does anyone happen to have some pointers in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't quite figure out how to do it purely with GORM, but some raw HQL worked:

```
def books = Book.findAll("from Book as b order by coalesce(b.sortTitle, b.title)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

`coalesce(book.sortTitle, book.title)`

[Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3266) you have the official Hibernate documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure on this but it seems to me that sorting by coalesce would lead to the database doing a file sort which could be rather expensive rather than being able to make use of an index.

My suggestion would be to always populate sortTitle with the name you want to sort by and then just use that.

Comment: Yeah, I was pondering DB impact. This is just an exercise to learn Grails and I wanted to solve this particular problem, but for a live production app I'd probably just set `sortTitle` to the value of `title` if `sortTitle` is left blank when creating the object.