# Grails Criteria get property with Coalesce

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

How do I use COALESCE in a grails hibernate **criteria**?

My scenario:

```
def c = b.createCriteria().list { 
  projections {
    groupProperty("name")
    count("name", 'myCount') 
  }
  order 'myCount'
}
```

Result:

```
{null: 1, 'Name 1': 2, 'Name 2': 3, ...}
```

I want to change the NULL for a string 'No data':

```
{'No data': 1, 'Name 1': 2, 'Name 2': 3, ...}
```

Like this SQL:

```
SELECT COALESCE(name, 'No data'), COUNT(*) FROM table_1
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Does any of the information at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756721/sorting-on-nullable-fields-in-gorm help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The question does not mention Criteria

Comment: Makes sense.  Best of luck.